# convert date to numeric and back to date

Tags: r, date, as.date

I have some date that I am trying to convert them to numbers and then back to original date.

```
      Date
1990-12-31 
1991-12-31 
1992-12-31 
1993-12-31 
1994-06-30 
1994-12-31
```

I tried,

```
as.numeric(DF[1:6])
[1]  1  2  3  5  7
as.Date(as.numeric(DF[1:6]), "1990-12-31")
[1] "1991-01-01" "1991-01-02" "1991-01-03" "1991-01-05" "1991-01-07" "1991-01-08"
```

I notice the problem of time interval. What should I do to get original dates?

Comment: Are you just trying to create a factor variable?

Comment: The fact `as.numeric(DF[1:6])` returns integers means that `class(DF$Date)` is `factor`. Use `as.Date` to convert directly to a date object. Note that you need to select the vector, not the whole data frame: `as.Date(DF$Date)`

Comment: If you'd rather use `[row, column]` notation: `as.Date(DF[1:6, 1])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you have is a data frame with a column of class `factor` as shown reproducibly in the Note at the end then we do not want to apply `as.numeric` to that since that will just give the underlying codes for the factor levels which are not meaningful. Rather, this gives `Date` class:

```
d <- as.Date(DF$Date)
d
## [1] "1990-12-31" "1991-12-31" "1992-12-31" "1993-12-31" "1994-06-30"
## [6] "1994-12-31"
```

and this gives the number of days since the UNIX Epoch:

```
no <- as.numeric(d)
no
## [1] 7669 8034 8400 8765 8946 9130
```

and this turns that back to `Date` class:

```
as.Date(no, "1970-01-01")
## [1] "1990-12-31" "1991-12-31" "1992-12-31" "1993-12-31" "1994-06-30"
## [6] "1994-12-31"
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
      Date
1990-12-31 
1991-12-31 
1992-12-31 
1993-12-31 
1994-06-30 
1994-12-31 "
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you! What if I have only month and year? the shortest answer I can think of is `format(as.Date(as.numeric(as.Date(paste(DF$Date,"-01",sep=" ")))), "%Y-%m")`. Any advice?

Comment: If your aim is just to convert a factor to a character string and f is the factor then as.character(f) or format(f)